# communicate politely error in report

Tags: management, employees

One of other department managers has sent me mail with invalid information in the report. How do I communicate politely error in report?

Comment: I think more context is needed for a good answer.  What kind of error?  What are the consequences of the error?  etc.

Comment: Ask to confirm the information without suggesting it could be an error

Comment: This is way too broad a topic for Q&A. A smaller scope would be required ("how do I communicate errors when [I'm new][I'm an outside consultant][...]". Note that "how do I tell person X from company Y about Z is usually also off-topic as too specific.

Answer (score 3):

Email back asking for clarification on what you believe to be erroneous is the best way. It gives them time to change it or explain it, without any embarrassment.

Comment: And saves you embarrassment if they were right.

Comment: I would add that if they sent this to many people, I prefer to help them save face by replying only to them and not to the group.